# How can I do a daily database backup for my VPS?

Tags: vps, database-backups

I currently have a VPS and I have the fear of something happening to it, either by me or by the hosting company, and so I need to have a daily backup sent to servers unrelated to that of the hosting company.

Essentially I need my server to automatically export my database into an SQL file and then send it to a third party server, idk, such as google or whatever, on a daily basis or even a few times every day so if something happens to the server the sql files will be accessible regardless.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

We are not suppose to write you a solution, only help you with coding errors etc.

Here's what you can do:

1. Create a shell script on the remote server that you want to save the database,this can be a mac or a linux box, we need cron an a shell.
2. Create a cron job to run dayly.

ShellScript Example. [dbBackup.sh]

```
#!/bin/bash
today =`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`;

ssh root@remoteServer.com mysqldump -u root --password=SomeDiffPassword databaseName > /home/user/DailyDatabaseBackups/database_$today.sql
```

Cron Example

```
* * * * * /home/user/dbBackup.sh
```